# Czes Kosniowski: Homeomorphic topological spaces $S^{1}\times I / \sim$ and $D^{2}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X=S^1\times I$ where $S^1\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $I=[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$ also define the equivalence relation ~ by $(x,t)$~$(y,s)$ if and only if $xt=ys$.

Prove that $X$/~ is homeomorphic to the unit disc $D^2=\{x\in \mathbb{R^2}: |x|\le1\}=\{x\in \mathbb{C}: |x|\le1\}$ with the induced topology.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by $xt = ys$? Is $I$ also being considered a subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Sorry $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ i will fix it

Comment: Try imagining the equivalence relation on X. It identifies less points then you might expect because if $x \neq y$ on the unit circle the only scalars you can multiply $x,y$ by to get them equal are 0 and 0. This construction is called the cone of $S^1$ which unsurprisingly is homeomorphic to a cone. So really what you want to show is that a cone is homeomorphic to a disc.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the function $f\colon S^1 \times I \to D^2$ defined by $f(x, t) = xt$. Show $f(x, t) = f(y, s)$ iff the pairs are equivalent, so $f$ induces a function on the quotient space

$$\bar{f}\colon (S^1 \times I)/\sim \to D^2 $$

Now show that this function is a homeomorphism.